# How to extract JSON from hashMap and add it to another JSONObject ?

Tags: android, json, hashmap

I have a HashMap in which I am saving JSONObject dynamically. There can be more than one JSONObjects in the hashMap. I want to extract them and add it to another JSONObject.

At the moment I am iterating through the map and extracting the JSONObjects and adding it to a String.

```
String personData = "";    
Iterator myVeryOwnIterator = map.keySet().iterator();
while(myVeryOwnIterator.hasNext()) 
{
    Integer key=(Integer)myVeryOwnIterator.next();
    JSONObject value;
    value= map.get(key);                    
    personData = personData + value.toString();                 
}
```

I tried creating another JSONObject to convert string 'personData' to JSONObject and add it to the main JSONObject incidentJson. But it has only one value, but String personData can have more than one JSON data.

```
JSONObject personDetailsJSON = new JSONObject(personData);
incidentJson.put("PersonDetails", personDetailsJSON);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this :

```
JSONObject personData = new JSONObject();

while (...) {
    Integer key=(Integer)myVeryOwnIterator.next();
    JSONObject value;
    value= map.get(key);                    
    personData.put(""+key, value);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. In this case as the name of the JSONObject keeps changing based on the key, will it not be a problem when reading the JSON as i will be sending this data to the server

Comment: I don't see what the problem would be. Basically you will send to the server something like this : `{"1":FirstJsonFromHashMap, "2":SecondJsonFromHashMap}` : where 1 and 2 are the keys from your HashMap and the jsons are your jsonObjects from HashMap (no mather if they have other childs).

Comment: Okay. I will do it this way. If any issues I will get back. Thanks for your help.